# Is there a something similar to " RRULE" of .ics ithat can be implemented in .CSV to use recurring events in google calendar import

Tags: csv, import, calendar, icalendar

I am trying to add a recurrent event every month , it works in .ics if i use something like
" RRULE FREQ=MONTHLY; UNTIL=20210310T045959Z;BYDAY=1MO" whereby i stated the end date of the recurring event inside and the frequency that i want it to be.

Is there an alternative to RRULE in .csv or  a way to implement this in .CSV?

Is there a better(more complete) documentation of "https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37118?hl=en" for the .csv or the .ics google calendar import

THanks

Answer (score 0):

The standard for calendars/events is the .ics format as per https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-8-5-3-recurrence-rule.html

Comma separated value files are not universally accepted by all applications and applications may have their own format in which they accept events for import.  I'm not aware of any that define a way to specify recurring events.  Some (Trumba?) explicity say that recurring events will be output as multiple single events.

EG:

google's is simple: "Subject    Start date  Start time "

From the links below one can see that each application expects an event .csv in a different format:

https://www.jevents.net/frequently-asked-questions/importing-events-in-csv-format

https://theeventscalendar.com/knowledgebase/k/csv-file-examples-for-importing/

https://time.ly/resources/additional-wordpress-settings/manage-add-ons/csv-import/

https://support.eventgeek.com/article/153-how-do-i-import-events-from-spreadsheet

Comment: Thank you very much for that explanation. It was exactly what i was looking for.